# C# Dapper one to many relationship with generics approach

Tags: c#, dapper

I have two models like these

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; } = new();
}   

public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int NumOfStudents { get; set;}
}
```

I have also a stored procedure for selecting all records.
My problem is how can make use of dapper with generics. In a general case i use this generic method

```
public List<T> LoadData<T, U>(string storedProcedure, U parameters, string connectionStringName)
{
     var connectionString = GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

     using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         var list = connection.Query<T>(storedProcedure, parameters,
             commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

        return list;
     }
 }
```

Now because of one-to-many relationship i am trying to use this generic method but with no success

```
public List<T> LoadMultipleData<T, L, U>(string storedProcedure, T parentModel, L childModel, U parameters, string connectionStringName)
{
     var connectionString = GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

     using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         var list= connection.Query<T, U, T>(storedProcedure, 
                                         (parent, child) =>
                                          {
                                             parent.parentModel = child;
                                             return parent;
                                          },
                                          parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

         return list;
     }
 }
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: See this: https://dapper-tutorial.net/result-multi-mapping

Comment: Note that Dapper uses 'splitOn' on multi mapping queries, so it can tell where an object ends and another starts, not sure if you doing this correctly on your SP, but clearly not doing this on the Dapper side

Answer (score 1):

After a long time i came up with a solution for this:

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> LoadMultipleDataAsync<TEntity, TManyEntity, TParameters>(string query, TParameters parameters, string connectionStringName)
{
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

    using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, TEntity>();
    var result = await connection.QueryAsync<TEntity, TManyEntity, TEntity>(query,
        (one, many) =>
        {
            var onePropertyInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id");
            var oneId = (int)onePropertyInfo?.GetValue(one);
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(oneId, out var currentOne))
            {
                currentOne = one;
                dictionary.Add(oneId, currentOne);
            }

            var manyPropertyType = typeof(TManyEntity).Name;
            var manyPropertyName = typeof(TEntity)?.GetProperty($"{manyPropertyType}es")?.Name;
            var list = (IList<TManyEntity>)currentOne?.GetType()?.GetProperty(manyPropertyName)?.GetValue(currentOne);                
            list.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, new object[] { many });

            return currentOne;
        }, parameters);

    return result.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

This solution supposes that the `Id` is always `int`.

In this line of code:

```
var manyPropertyName = typeof(TEntity)?.GetProperty($"{manyPropertyType}es")?.Name;
```

We refer to the plural of `Class` (Classes), via reflection, but this is only a sample and could be improved (e.g with `Attributes`).

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```cs
public List<T> LoadMultipleData<T, L, U>(string storedProcedure, T parentModel, L childModel, U parameters, string connectionStringName)
{
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var parents = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        var list= connection.Query<T, U, T>(storedProcedure, 
                                         (parent, child) =>
                                          {
                                             T foundParent;
                                             if (!parents.TryGetValue(parent.id, out foundParent))
                                             {
                                                 foundParent = parent;
                                                 parents.Add(foundParent.id, foundParent);
                                             } 
                                             foundParent.parentModel = child;
                                             return foundParent;
                                          },
                                          parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

         return list.Distinct(); // or return parents if you like.
    }
}
```

The `splitOn` parameter is not needed if your fields are named "Id". You should remember that any join returns a 2D "table" and the parents (left side of the join) will be multiplied as many times as they have children. That's why you need the parents dictionary to keep trak of whether it's a "new" parent or an existing one.

Comment: It's just me or this code doesn't even compile? `T doesn't contain a definition for id`.